Можно ли использовать метод наименьших квадратов для уравнения y = a0 + a1*x1 + a2*x2 + a3*x3, где x3=x2^2, а x1 = ∫x2dt (интеграл от х2)
Стоит задача определения параметров некоторой системы y = a0 + a1x1 + a2x2 + a3*x3. Пытаюсь определить параметры a0..a3 методом наименьших квадратов. Нюанс заключается в том, что x3=x2^2, а x1 = ∫x2dt (интеграл от х2).
Для оценки работы алгоритма использую некоторые тестовые наборы значений с известными a0..a3, и считаю их методом МНК, но не получаю искомые значения.
Пример в матлаб:
A = [0.5; 1; 1.5; -2]; # вектор параметров a0..a3
x2 = 0:0.01:1; # 
X = [ones(size(x2)); cumtrapz(x2)*0.01; x2; x2.^2]'; # матрица регрессоров
Y = X*A; # вектор зависимой переменной y
Beta = pinv(X)*Y; # оценки МНК
Y_est = X*Beta; # вычисление зависимой переменной на основе оценок МНК
plot(Y) 
hold on
plot(Y_est)

При вычислении Beta  получаю вектор [0.5000; -0.6000; 1.5000; -1.2000].
Подскажите, что делаю не так, и корректен ли вообще такой подход? Возможно есть какие-то альтернативы

Вы бы как-то использовали /, или хотя бы ^/_ для степеней/индексов, а то непонятно... И потом, интеграл... Т.е. это у вас какие-то функции?

да, х1, х2, х3 - это функции времени, причем взаимосвязаны между собой. x3 - x2 в квадрате, а x1 интеграл от x2

Тогда как вы хотите применять МНК? Для решения дифференциального уравнения? Что у вас вообще задано, какие входные данные?

х2, у - измеряются, х3 и х1  вычисляются на основе тех формул, что я привел выше. Имеется достаточно большая выборка, каждому конкретному набору значений  x1i, x2i, x3i,,соответствует yi. Характер зависимости y от х1...х3 известен. Неизвестны коэффициенты. Для их определения я и хочу использовать МНК

Ну, константу интегрирования можно запихнуть в a_0, так что пределы интегрирования не важны. Но вот сама функциональная зависимость... Вам надо именно матлаб?

матлаб использую исключительно для проверки алгоритма, который в дальнейшем перенесу на микроконтроллер

Ну, поскольку я в матлабе не силен :), лично я бы набросал что-то свое, чтоб убедиться в том, что эти зависимости действительно работают... Но есть еще и вопрос XY-проблемы — может, вашу (исходную!) задачу лучше иным методом решать...
